# How to make this coroutine work like update function

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Basically, this code Resizes a gameobject from bigger to smaller then smaller to bigger..(repeat)

Now what will you do if you want it go smaller to bigger or bigger to smaller by setting the bool repeatable to true or false when the game is running.

Like, in update function we have if function. I want that this happens `yield return RepeatLerp(minScale, maxScale, duration);` while the mouse is down and this happens `yield return RepeatLerp(tramsform.localscale // (current size of object), minScale, duration);` while the mouse is up.

```
public class TouchMechanic : MonoBehaviour {
    Vector3 minScale;
    public Vector3 maxScale;
    public bool repeatable;
    public float speed = 2f;
    public float duration = 5f;  
    public float timeStartedlerping ;  

    public float z;

IEnumerator Start()
     {
         minScale = transform.localScale;
         while (repeatable)
         {
             yield return RepeatLerp(minScale, maxScale, duration);
             yield return RepeatLerp(maxScale, minScale, duration);
         }
     }
     public IEnumerator RepeatLerp(Vector3 a, Vector3 b, float time)
     {
         float i = 0.0f;
         float rate = (1.0f / time) * speed;


             while (i < 1.0f)
             {
                 i += Time.deltaTime * rate;
                 transform.localScale = Vector3.Lerp(a, b, i);
                 yield return null;
             }    

     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears yout want your code to work like this:

1. When the coroutine is invoked, the current scale is recorded as minimum scale.
2. The object's scale is lerped up to maxScale.
3. The object's scale is lerped back to the original scale.

Your code is a bit overcomplicated. Hopefully this code achieves the same as what you want, but  can simplify it a bit.

```
IEnumerator ExpandContract(Vector3 minScale, Vector3 maxScale, float duration)
{
    float time = 0f;
    while(transform.localScale < maxScale) //While the current scale has not reached its max, keep expanding.
    {
        transform.localScale = Vector3.Lerp(minScale, maxScale, time / duration);
        time += time.deltaTime;
        yield return null;
    }
    time = 0f;
    while(transform.localScale > minScale) //While the current scale has not yet returned to its original size, keep shrinking.
    {
        transform.localScale = Vector3.Lerp(maxScale, minScale, time / duration);
        time += time.deltaTime;
        yield return null;
    }
}
```

In order to invoke this coroutine, you would need to call:

```
StartCoroutine(ExpandContract(minScale, maxScale, duration))
```

Since the method is not marked as public, you can only start the coroutine from within the same method. You can expose it via something like this

```
public void StartExpandContract()
{
    Vector3 minScale = transform.localScale;   
    StartCoroutine(ExpandContract(minScale, maxScale, duration));
}
```

You can then call the "StartExpandContract()" method from anywhere else in your project as long as you have a reference to your TouchMechanic component. Alternatively, you could add an Update() loop that checks for user input and invokes "StartExpandContract()" on mouse or key button press like this:

```
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown("space"))
    {
        StartExpandContract();
    }
}
```

The entire script would look something like this:

```
public class TouchMechanic : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public Vector3 maxScale;
    public float duration = 5f;  
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown("space"))
        {
            StartExpandContract();
        }
    }

    public void StartExpandContract()
    {
        Vector3 minScale = transform.localScale;   
        StartCoroutine(ExpandContract(minScale, maxScale, duration));
    }

    IEnumerator ExpandContract(Vector3 minScale, Vector3 maxScale, float duration)
    {
        float time = 0f;
        while(transform.localScale < maxScale) //While the current scale has not reached its max, keep expanding.
        {
            transform.localScale = Vector3.Lerp(minScale, maxScale, time / duration);
            time += time.deltaTime;
            yield return null;
        }
        time = 0f;
        while(transform.localScale > minScale) //While the current scale has not yet returned to its original size, keep shrinking.
        {
            transform.localScale = Vector3.Lerp(maxScale, minScale, time / duration);
            time += time.deltaTime;
            yield return null;
        }
    }
}
```